# Gradle не может скачать jar файлы

Tags: java, gradle

Ссылки работаю перехожу все качает, но выходит ошибка:

> Task :netbeans-gradle-plugin:compileJava FAILED
>   :netbeans-gradle-plugin:compileJava (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 21 mins 10.995 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':netbeans-gradle-plugin:compileClasspath'.

  > Could not download org-netbeans-modules-maven.jar (org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-maven:dev-SNAPSHOT:20171112.071152-1)
  >   Could not get resource 'http://bits.netbeans.org/netbeans/trunk/new-maven-snapshot/org/netbeans/modules/org-netbeans-modules-maven/dev-SNAPSHOT/org-netbeans-modules-maven-dev-20171112.071152-1.jar'.
  >   Read timed out
  >   Could not download org-netbeans-modules-maven-model.jar (org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-maven-model:dev-SNAPSHOT:20171112.071041-1)
  >   Could not get resource 'http://bits.netbeans.org/netbeans/trunk/new-maven-snapshot/org/netbeans/modules/org-netbeans-modules-maven-model/dev-SNAPSHOT/org-netbeans-modules-maven-model-dev-20171112.071041-1.jar'.
  >   Read timed out
  >   Could not download maven-aether-provider.jar (org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:3.3.9)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-aether-provider/3.3.9/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-aether-provider/3.3.9/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar'.
  >   Read timed out
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21m 13s
10 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 4 up-to-date

Comment: Да нет, не всё качает - вылетает из-за проблем с интернетом. Возможно Джаву блокирует антивирус.

Comment: а как дать разрешение антивирусу?(windows 10 defender)

Comment: Обычно окошко само выскакивает с запросом на разрешение для внешних и внутренних сетей - достаточно установить доступ к внутренним сетям. Но как быть, если уже случайно ответили отказом - сразу не скажу.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что для вашей `IDE` открыт доступ к интернету: откройте через панель управления параметры исключений `брандмауэра` (`Панель управления`\ `Система и безопасность`\ `Брандмауэр Защитника Windows`\ `Разрешенные программы`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скорее всего вам нужно искать программу `NetBeans`, но точное название может быть другим.
Если у неё отсутствует галочка в колонке `Частная` - установите её предварительно включив режим `Изменить параметры` (правый верхний угол).

Если программы нет в списке, её можно добавить кнопкой `Разрешить другое приложение...`.